# PfSense Authorative Name Server of a subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, pfsense, internal-dns, dns-hosting

I have PfSense running currently with DNS and DHCP but I recently purchased a domain name and now I would like to have PfSense be a name server for a sub-domain but internal only. Currently host names resolve as expected as HOSTNAME/ in a browser and I would like to keep that and have them resolve as HOSTNAME.subdomain.domain.tld and have everything else forwarded out, which it does currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in DHCP/DNS had an option for a domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but you need to install a new package. Go to *System* > *Packages* > *Available Packages* and download package `dns-server` or `TinyDns` and it will be added to *Services* menu.

In your use case you need to *bind* it to the LAN interface and use it also as a *recursive DNS resolver* for LAN, so that it serves both your local `subdomain.example.com` and does recursion to the rest. Then go to the N*ew domain wizard* and add domain `subdomain.example.com`.

As you wanted to have `hostname.subdomain.example.com` for your whole internal network, you might be interested in the two options for registering DHCP mappings & leases with the DNS server.

As you only use this locally you don't need to *delegate* control of the subdomain to your internal DNS server; it will believe it is the authoritative name server for this domain before it does any recursion.

Comment: I am using the default DNS and DHCP included with pfsense, I assume I have to disable the default DNS before doing what you have suggested?

Comment: If installing the alternative DNS server doesn't do this automatically, then yes.

Comment: [2.3_Removed_Packages](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/2.3_Removed_Packages)
dns-server was removed from the package manager for 2.3
I don't see Tiny-Dns in this list though, and I don't see it in the package manager.

Comment: I don't see Tiny-Dns in the list of available packages either: [Package_list](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Package_list)

Comment: I see the bind package, but its description says GUI for Bind, and its [dependency](https://www.freshports.org/dns/bind-pfsense),bind-pfsense-9.11.1, has no port information